# Trying to get the current date with a specific format but Date is coming with a expected way

Tags: date, groovy, soapui

Here is the code and output. Please let me know what's wrong with the code.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def myDate=new Date()

def sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY")

return sdf.format(myDate)

log.info sdf.format(myDate)
```

Op-: 04/94/2016

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the above in a groovy script, do not require `return` statement.

Comment: Yes                                           TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
def now = new Date();
def tomorrow=now + 1
def ExecutionStartDate = tomorrow.format("MM/dd/yyyy")                                  And this is working for me

Answer (score 3):

You need lower case `dd` ***AND*** `yyyy`

You can also call format on dates directly in groovy

```
date.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Also, if this is to be read by anyone outside the US, or you want to be able to sort dates alphabetically, consider the more universal (iso8601) format of

```
date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

As AR.3 said in their answer, the [documentation for simpledateformat can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)